# Umbraco Json to css class="[]"

Tags: html, css, json, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-cms/) and is working with the data-type grid layout and want to add custom settings (css classes) to each row/cell and it kinda work. User interface:

[image]

The "modifier": "{X}" give different results the 3 worked "best".

And the json:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Message Box",
    "description": "Message Box",
    "key": "class",
    "view": "checkbox",
    "modifier": "{3}",
    "applyTo": "cell",
    "config": {
      "items": {
        "key1": {
          "value": "value1"
        },
        "key2": {
          "value": "value2"
        },
        "key3": {
          "value": "value3"
        },
        "key4": {
          "value": "value4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But the cell/rows that i apply these classes to end up looking like this

```
<div class="["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"]">
```

And the html cant understand these classes when they have [] and commas after how can i make so the classes is applied propperly to the elements?

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DP8upvUu) of the modified Foundation5

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5wQ096ma) of Umbracos checkbox code

Comment: Which template engine is Umbraco using for HTML templates?

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski I am using Foundation5 that i have modified a bit

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski https://pastebin.com/DP8upvUu

Comment: Foundation is only the CSS framework. I mean the template engine for instance Twig. But maybe you're not using one. Could you show us your code where you're putting the classes in?

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski https://pastebin.com/5wQ096ma Its the standard code from umbraco none changed

Comment: Just paste your code into your question. This is the main part for solving your problem. Also highlight or mark the line, where the classes are added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170271/discussion-between-michael-czechowski-and-patte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedItems', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.model.value = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.selectedItems.length; x++) {
            if ($scope.selectedItems[x].checked) {
                $scope.model.value.push($scope.selectedItems[x].key);
            }
        }
    }, true);
```

Into this:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedItems', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var classList = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.selectedItems.length; x++) {
            if ($scope.selectedItems[x].checked) {
                classList.push($scope.selectedItems[x].key);
            }
        }
        $scope.model.value = classList.join(' '); // imploding class list
    }, true);
```

Instead of adding the whole array with the class list to your front end, you should implode your array and split the individual classes by a whitespace.

Comment: Sadly not, but i know what you tried to do so i think i can tweak that to get it to work

Comment: @Patte Oh, there was a mistake in the code. I'll fix it.